# Difference between Container and ContainerBuilder in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to understand the Symfony core, but I'm not not completely sure about some things happening in the DI component.

What is the difference between the `Container` and the `ContainerBuilder`? The name would suggest that the `ContainerBuilder` is used to build a `Container` object, but regarding the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) it can be directly instantiated and used as a container:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container->register('mailer', 'Mailer');
```

Why not use `$container = new Container()` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, below from Symfony's documentation (http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.html):

> ```
> class ContainerBuilder extends Container implements TaggedContainerInterface
> ```
>
> **ContainerBuilder is a DI container that provides an API to easily describe services.**

You see, `ContainerBuilder` **extends** `Container`. Compare the documentation with http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the very class-definition of ContainerBuilder:

Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:

```
class ContainerBuilder extends Container implements TaggedContainerInterface
```

So, `ContainerBuilder` is basically a `Container`, it just adds some functionality. For example `Container` does not have a `register` method like you gave in your example.

Comment: Agree, but "adds" could also be "replaces", conform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle